# Domain Access and websites for multiple countries

Tags: domain-access, subsites

I currently have this url structure for nodes town.domain I would like to add country into that url to make it domain/country/town/type. My question is how do I achieve this on drupal 7?

practical example ureport.com/ke/mombasa/business

Comment: Why don't you use country_name.example.com instead of example.com/country_name?

Comment: This is going to depend largely on how you organize your content under those urls. Will the content be in different languages, or, what else determines what content belongs where?

Comment: You should check what choice meets your requirements "domain access" or multisite.

Comment: I already used domain access. I would like to try multisite with different database, share the user information, edit the domain access domains because each country site has different counties.

Comment: Hello Gisle by going to ureport.co.ke you will understand what I mean. The stories as county specific for kenya. Now I need to setup three multi-sites for tanzania and uganda. I want the url to read ureport.co.ke/country name eg ureport.co.ke/tanzania. Thus if you want stories from a county or province in tanzania, the url will change to county.ureport.co.ke/tanzania. I hope I am clearer now.